# CSS text-align: center not working pls

Tags: html, css, alignment

```
 <div class="bgwhite" style="padding-top: 100px;">
     <div style="text-align: center">
       <center> pikachu </center>
     </div>
```

I dont know what is going wrong :/

pls help

Comment: This snippet is not enough to gauge what is happening. Is there any other CSS being applied in the header/external? Why do you have center tags? Use a DOM editor/inspector to see the size/orientation of this div vs. it's parents. The text probably IS centered, but the parent is not where you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have the outer `div` tag closed. Add `</div>` to your snippet and try again.

By the way, it is not recommended using `<center>` tag anymore. Check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) for details. So your snippets should be like this:

```html
<div class="bgwhite" style="padding-top: 100px;">
     <div style="text-align: center">
       pikachu
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrHydeGaming By checking your link, it works as expected from my view. the sentence `This line will be centered` is centered.

Comment: @shisaw yeah but idk why it does not :/ bug?

Comment: @MrHydeGaming I'm not quite sure about that. Maybe because some plugins in your browser affected the CSS? You can run your code locally and use different browsers by disabling plugins and try again.

Comment: @shisaw I figured it out... took me more than 6 hrs... Bootstrap class "row" is incompatible with algin classes... and other stuff too

Answer (score 0):

your code absolutely right check this code in another browser
when I run your code it works perfectly

(sorry for bad English)
[chekout this output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oyfx.png)